# How to have unicode characters in Django model choices?

Tags: python, django, unicode

I'm trying to have special characters in field choices. I have the following code:

```
CHOICES = (('1', 'b'),
                ('2', 'p'),
                ('3', 'm'),
                ...
                ('11', '&#638;'),
                ...)
field = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

However when Django renders the select list for that field what I get is this:

```
<option value="11">&amp;#638;</option>
```

I tried manually printing the special characters and it works. But for some reason Django is converting the `&` to `&amp;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Python Unicode object as your label:

```
CHOICES = (('1', 'b'),
                ('2', 'p'),
                ('3', 'm'),
                ...
                ('11', u'\u027e'),
                ...)
```

Django will encode the character when rendering.